# Prove that $MN = \dfrac{|b − c|}{2}$

Tags: geometry, triangles

> In triangle $ABC$, point $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$ and $N$ is on the angle bisector of $\angle A$ such that $MN \parallel AB$. Prove that $MN = \dfrac{|b − c|}{2}$.

**Attempt**: I drew it out and noticed that $\triangle{DMN}\sim\triangle{DBA}$. I am not sure how to use the fact that $M$ is the midpoint yet, but I think the angle bisector theorem will help. We have $\dfrac{BD}{c} = \dfrac{a/2+DM}{b}$. Then by the similarity $\dfrac{DM}{BD} = \dfrac{MN}{c}$. I am not sure what to do next.

[image]

Comment: Note that by angle bisector theorem, we can easily take out values of $BD$ and $CD$. Putting them in the similarity condition will give you the answer.

Comment: There's another alternative way: let $E$ be the intersection of $MN$ and $AC$. Then, as $\angle NAE = \angle ENA$, we have $NE=AE$. Thus,
$$MN=NE-ME=AE-ME=\frac{b-c}2$$.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. Let $BD=x,DM=y$. Then,
$$\frac{x}{c}=\frac{y+a/2}{b}$$
The other equality in $x$ and $y$ come from the fact that
$$x+y=\frac{a}{2}$$
This is where the midpoint comes in. Now solve for $x$ and $y$, and use the condition of similarity
$$\frac{c}{x}=\frac{MN}{y}$$
This gives
$$MN=\frac{b-c}{2}$$
EDITS:
There is an alternative case in which having the same definitions would give
$$x-y=\frac{a}{2}$$
$$\frac{x}{c}=\frac{a/2-y}{b}$$
Solving these gives the other part and using the similarity condition (you can check this still holds),
$$MN=\frac{c-b}{2}$$
Hope it helps !

Comment: The problem with this solution is that $x+y$ is not always equal to $a/2$.

Comment: You are right, thanks for pointing that out. Fixing.